# Scope of SavePoint variable

Tags: dml, savepoint

I am trying to upsert parent records in a class as well as it calls another class which inserts child records. I am trying to add Savepoint to rollback the transaction and prevent parent record from upserting , if child upsertion fails.
Below is high level code

```
// Class A 

Class A{
    // statements and methods
if(condition){
    try{
         // statements
         **Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();**
         **Database.upsert(Parentrecords);**  
    }
    catch(DMLException dmlex){
        //log dml exception errors
    }
    catch(Exception){
        // log exceptions
    }
}
method() // Some method called
// Some statements, loops etc

if(condition){
    // Some more statements
    boolean isUpserted;
    **isUpserted = B.upsertChildRecords(childrecords);
    if(!isUpserted){
        Database.rollback(sp);
    }**
}
}
// Class B 

Class B {
    boolean upsertChildRecords(list childrecords){
        try{
        database.upsert(childrecords);
        return true;
        }
        catch(DMLexception exception){
            //log dml exception
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**It throws error- Variable does not exist: sp**
What is the scope of the savepoint variable?

Comment: Scope is same as any other variable. You need to define it before try/catch block

Comment: Thanks.It helps.You can put that as an answer , I will close this thread.